# How to check for `nil` in while loop condition in Swift?

Tags: swift

How to check for `nil` in while loop in Swift? I'm getting error on this:

```
var count: UInt = 0
var view: UIView = self
while view.superview != nil { // Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue UIView, NilLiteralConvertible)'
    count++
    view = view.superview
}
// Here comes count...
```

I'm currently using Xcode6-Beta7.

Comment: Are you sure this is complete code ? You are assigning `UIView?` to `UIView` variable, that should be the first and only error at this code. Try to fix it with `view = view.superview!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cannot compile. `nil` can only appear in optionals.
You need to declare `view` with optional, `var view: UIView? = self.superview`.
Then compare it with `nil` in the while-loop.

```
var count: UInt = 0
var view: UIView? = self.superview
while view != nil { // Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue UIView, NilLiteralConvertible)'
    count++
    view = view!.superview
}
```

Or do a `let` binding, But it seems not necessary here, I think.

Comment: "nil can only appear in optionals." or any type which conforms to `NilLiteralConvertible`

Answer (score 86):

The syntax of `while` allows for optional binding.  Use:

```
var view: UIView = self
while let sv = view.superview {
  count += 1
  view = sv
}
```

[Thanks to @ben-leggiero for noting that `view` need not be `Optional` (as in the question itself) and for noting Swift 3 incompatibilities]

Comment: Works but 2. row should be `while let super = view?.superview {`. Thank you, I'm accepting the other answer with explanation.

Comment: Hm... I think `view` can be non-optional; it starts out with a non-optional value (`self` is never `nil`) and always gets assigned a non-optional value (if `super` is `nil`, the loop ends and it's never assigned to `view`)

Comment: Also this doesn't compile; `super` is a reserved keyword and `++` was removed in Swift 3

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for that!