# While with assignment in swift

Tags: swift

What is the proper way to convert this Objective-C code into Swift?

```
while ((size = [inputdata readWithByteArray:buf]) != -1) {
  //...
}
```

I need similar to this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25668371/1979882)):

```
while let super = view?.superview {
  count++
  view = super
}
```

but in my case i have to compare the value with `-1` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `while case` with a binding pattern plus a boolean condition:

```
// Swift 3 (Xcode 8):
while case let size = inputdata.readWithByteArray(&buf), size != -1 {
    // process data

}

// Swift 2 (Xcode 7.3.1):
while case let size = inputdata.readWithByteArray(&buf) where size != -1 {
    // process data

}
```

---

*(Previous answers:)* A straight-forward implementation would look like this:

```
var size = inputdata.readWithByteArray(&buf)
while size != -1 {
    // process data ...

    size = inputdata.readWithByteArray(&buf)
}
```

If the code-duplication bothers you then you can write it also as
(Swift 3/Xcode 8 only):

```
var size: Int
while (size = inputdata.readWithByteArray(&buf), size).1 != -1 {
    // process data

}
```

Here the `(...).1` expression evaluates to the second tuple element,
i.e. to `size`, and the first tuple element is only evaluated for
its side-effect. (This is possible in Swift because expressions
are evaluated from left to right, as stated by Chris Lattner
in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20001#63783.)

Comment: what does `.1` mean?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: I think I have found a nicer solution, see update.

Comment: 10x. but save the answer with `.1` value. This is rather interesting implementation, imo.

Comment: > Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Which Xcode version are you using? I tested the code with Xcode 8.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: For Xcode 7 you have to write `where size != -1` instead of `, size != -1`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the tuple-based code from the accepted answer quite interesting for solving the issue posted in the question.

> Here the `if (..., boolean).1 {` expression evaluates the second tuple element, a boolean, and the first tuple element is only evaluated for its side-effect.

So you can do things like inline the index decrement *in* the while loop condition, rather than on a line before or after:

```
var index = 5
while (index -= 1, index >= 0).1 {
    print(index)
}

// 4
// 3
// 2
// 1
// 0
```

Whereas the `while case let` construct does not allow the previous assignments to `index` to persist in the next iteration of the loop:

```
var index = 0
while case let index = index + 1 {
    print(index)
}

// 1
// 1
// 1
// 1
// infinite loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `++` in Swift 3.0; you can replace `i` to your condition

```
var i = 10
while i != -1 {
    print("----")
    print(i)
    i -= 1
}
```

Comment: FYI - `i = i-1` is better written as `i -= 1`. That's the clearer way to replace `i--`.