# EXC_BAD Instruction when convert Any to Int in swift

Tags: json, swift, int

My json object is in this way

```
["Success": 0, "Message": Tenant not found, "ControlId": <null>, "Source": <null>, "Result": 0, "ErrorCode": 4, "Description": ]
```

This is the code I use to check the Success value.

```
 if (response.result.value as? [String: Any]) != nil {
                    // ...
                    let json=response.result.value as? [String: Any]
                    print(json!)
                    let successCode:Int=json!["Success"] as! Int
                    if(successCode==0)
                    {
                        dm.errorMessage=json!["Message"] as! String
                        callback("error")
                    }
                    else if(successCode>0)
                    {
                        dm.responseDict=json
                        callback("success")
                    }



                }
```

But I am getting this error
[image]

What is the reason for this? And how to solve this?
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: What does `type(of: json!["Success"]!)` say?

Comment: Its bool value. But in line 46 I get the 0 as success value. And The mentioned json string is the one I got from line 46

Comment: There is a blog entry from Apple: [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37), which in particular demonstrates how to use *optional casting* with JSON elements.

Comment: @MartinR This just blew my mind: `for case let string as String in array`. Didn't know case expressions applied to for loops.

Comment: @Alexander: One can do nice things with the case pattern, here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39793752/1187415.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the code crashes the value for key `Success` is either `Bool` or `String`.

Basically your code is very *objectivecish*, this is a *swiftier* version

```
if let result = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
    print(result)
    //TODO: Handle optional safely
    let success = result["Success"] as! Bool
    if success {
       dm.responseDict = result
       callback("success")
    } else {
       //TODO: Handle optional safely
       dm.errorMessage= result["Message"] as! String
       callback("error")
    }
} else {
   callback("result is not a dictionary")
}
```

Comment: Do you really recommend the force-casting (as! Bool, as! String)?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I do. The server sends a string `message` if `success` is `false`. If the provider ever change the data structure the app crashes (keeping the exclamation marks) or does nothing. What is the difference? The app will be defective anyway.

Comment: Well, an application crash is acceptable for *programming errors* (to find and fix them during development) but (in my opinion) not for unexpected  data from external sources which are not directly under program control. (Not my vote btw)

Comment: @MartinR I know you weren't the downvoter. I just answered the question. The OP is responsible for handling the optionals. Maybe my answer is a bit provoking. I don't like the *exclamation-marks-are-always-evil* dogma. ;-) I take all downvotes I get and will not delete the answer.

Comment: PS: I edited my answer adding `todo` comments like in the other – upvoted but also potentially crashing – answer.

Comment: @vadian I'm not a fan of force unwrapping in this case because it is left unclear whether the author of the code is intentionally force unwrapping, or is unknowingly introducing the potential to crash. Even if I were okay with crashing upon receiving malformed input (which I'm usually not), I would still unwrap safely, then call `fatalError`, `preconditionFailure`, etc. to give a more descriptive cause for the error. That clearly communicates my attention to crash, and makes it clear that I wasn't just slacking and `!`ing all the things

Comment: @Alexander I'm a bit kidding. Only the OP can judge how to handle the optionals.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just go around force casting and force unwrapping everything. Don't be surprised when your application crashes due to your unfounded assumptions about the datatypes in play. Use conditional binding to handle errors appropriately:

```
guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
    //TODO: Handle error here safely
    fatalError("response.result.value is not of type [String: Any].")
}

print(json)

guard let successCode = json["Success"] as? Int else {
    //TODO: Handle error here safely
    fatalError("successCode doesn't exist or exists but is not valid a valid Int.")
}

switch successCode {
    case 0:
        guard let message = json["Message"] as? String else {
            //TODO: Handle error here safely
            fatalError("Messange not present, or is not a String.")
        }
        dm.errorMessage = message
        callback("error")

    case 1...Int.max:
        dm.responseDict = json
        callback("success")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your expectation :)

Comment: I tried to edit the guys best answer with what you just wrote.
Forgot it doesn't work like that, got rejected. But thanks for doing this yourself :) definitely not "swifty" to force unwrap with bangs! like that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than force-unwrapping using `!`, use `?`.  This will prevent the app from crashing.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: You are correct.  My bad.  My rep is too low to comment.  I should've withheld.